# RxJS BehaviorSubject: return current value or get a new one based on condition

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a subject that consumers are subscribed to:

```
private request$: Subject<Service> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

This is the function that my components call upon initialisation:

```
public service(id: number): Observable<Service> {
    return this.request$
        .pipe(
            switchMap((request) => request && request.serviceId ? of(request) : this.requestById(id)));
}
```

and the service call:

```
private requestById(serviceId: number): Observable<Service> {
    // http call 
}
```

Different components call this function with different `id`s. I'd like to renew/update the subject if the incoming `id` parameter value doesn't match of the `id` value of the current subject.

Is that possible to do? I have seen an `iif` function, but I don't think it suits me fully.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
public service(id: number): Observable<Service> {
    return this.request$
        .pipe(
          //this is needed to ensure to avoid second evalution after doing next once
          //we got the new service value from the API
          take(1),
          switchMap((request) => {
            if(request && request.serviceId === id) {
              return of(request);
            } else {
              return this.requestById(id) 
                         .pipe(
                           //i am assuming that response of this.requestById is an instance of 'Service'; 
                           //update the subject
                           tap(s => this.requests$.next(s))
                         );
            }
          })
        );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work. The `subject` is sometimes updated. The reason for this is that strangely request `Subject` sometimes arrives as null even though it has previous value and `id` is the same.

Comment: @DenissM. This should not happen. I could only think of some race condition in which multiple components try to subscribe to return observable of `service()` API and for one API response has emitted the new value in `subject` while other has just subscribed before next value was emitted. To avoid it, I am using `take(1)`. Did you notice `take(1)` in my solution?

Comment: yes I did. But it doesn't work :( I'm also using take(1). Could it happen because when I browse different components -> in some I am unsubscribing from this service() (intentionally during OnDestroy) and this way the subscription happens again -> new (same) value is fetched from API?

Comment: @DenissM. I would be able to better answer if I could see your components hierarchy or how various components are composed in a page and how those components make use of this service. But I am sure that the same behavior subject cannot emit two different values to multiple subscribers if the value is not changed i.e. it will emit always same value to multiple subscribers until the next `next`

Comment: That is also what I assume. I need to trace from where this null value is coming and why it happens only sometimes.

Comment: after some debugging -> your solution worked perfectly. The problem was in another place. Thanks!